# Give an example of a function $f$ for which the following assertion is false.

Tags: calculus, limits

Give an example of a function $f$ for which the following assertion is false.

If $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon$ when $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - l| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $0 < |x-a| < \frac{\delta}{2}$.

I read the answer book for Spivak's calculus. The choice is $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ with $a=0$ and $l=0$. I can follow the example. But why can we specify that $a=0$ and $l=0$?

Can I pick $f(x) = x^2$ and $a=0$ and $l=0$?

If $0 < |x| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$, then $|x^2| < \epsilon$. If $0< |x| < \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$, then $|x^2| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. But $\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ is not equal to $\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}{2}$

Comment: For a counterexample only need (any) specific example where false. For your other example you changed Spivak's function and just got another which seems not to work. But finding "counterexamples" which don't work is always irrelevant.

Comment: The final $\epsilon$ in your first paragraph might be a typo for $\delta$?

Comment: @coffeemath Do you mean the counterexample I gave actually is not a counterexample?

Comment: John: Your "counterexample", if it is a case of the general statement of the first display of your post, should have its epsilon in the "then" part equal to half the epsilon in the "if" part. But you did not do that.

Comment: Your counterexample $x^2$ when $a=l=0$ fails to be a counterexample, for example if one takes $\epsilon=1/4. \delta=1/2.$ For in that case the second part of the if-then says $|x^2|<1/8$ when $|x|<1/4$ which is true. [because if $|x|<1/4$ then it's actually less than $1/16<1/8.$

Comment: And if $0< |x| <\frac{\sqrt\epsilon}2$ then
$|x^2| < \frac{\epsilon}4<\frac{\epsilon}2.$